# How does Cheat Code interact with Monster's Ballroom?

Tags: boss-monster

Cheat Code's Boss Item ability allows a player to choose a room in any dungeon and ignore its ability text for the duration of a turn. Monster's Ballroom deals damage *, where * is equal to the number of Monster Rooms in the dungeon it is in, but I am unsure whether the explanation for the * is considered ability text or if it should just be seen as explaining how to resolve the *. I checked the [Room Card wikia page](http://bossmonster.wikia.com/wiki/Rooms) to see if Monster's Ballroom's text fell under any of the Room Ability categories and it seems to fall under passive, but this doesn't really get me any closer to an answer on this.

[image: cheat code]
[image: monster's Ballroom]

How does Cheat Code affect Monster's Ballroom? Does it remove the text that determines how the * is calculated and thus force this room to deal 0 damage for a turn? If the damage isn't simply set to 0 for the turn, how is the damage determined?

Or does Cheat Code simply not affect Monster's Ballroom, under the idea that the card's text is not considered an ability, but rather an explanation of the * (implying this card has no ability in lieu of it having the potential to be rather powerful)? I assume that this would be how Cheat Code would interact with Dragon Hatchery, as its "ability text" only says "This Room contains all four treasure types", but simply ignoring this text doesn't change the fact that it has all four Treasure Type icons, so I'm wondering if Cheat Code is similarly ineffective here.

Answer (score 1):

What makes this room special is that its ability is not just a passive ability, but a *characteristic-defining* ability.

I can see both interpretations as valid. But in the absence of anything rules to the contrary, you are instructed to ignore the ability, so you should ignore the ability.

The room therefore deals an undefined amount of damage, and therefore no damage.

Comment: In M:TG, if an object loses all abilities, that includes characteristic-defining abilities, but that's hardly binding.